# How do i find the volume of this paraboloid using triple interal

Tags: integration

I need to find the volume of this paraboloid, $x^2+y^2=z,z=4y,$ using triple integrals, but have trouble determining the limits of integration.

I know it's an inverted paraboloid with the plane $z=4y$ cutting at top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intersect the surfaces $$x^2+y^2=z=4y$$ you get the circle $x^2+(y-2)^2=4$ and you see that in the following plot. Now, take a look at that circle to find the ranges for $$\theta,~~\text{and}~~~r$$ In fact, I want to use *Cylindrical Coordinates* here. As you see, the volume is symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y$ so we consider the part which is established on $x\ge 0, y\ge 0$. The second Fig below shows that $$r|_{0}^{4\sin\theta}, ~\theta|_{0}^{\pi/2}$$ So we have $$V=2\int_{\theta}\int_{r}\int_{z=r^2}^{4r\sin\theta}rdzdrd\theta$$
[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Your skill in drawing figures is surprising for me. :)
Happy Eid! (kam peida boodin ye moddat!)

Comment: Thanks! ishalla ebadate shoma ham ghabool bashe.

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks !!, can you also tell me what will the limits be in cartesian co-ordinates ? as i am not able to see that yet and it would help me understand it better.

Comment: @AmanMittal: $$2\int_{y=0}^4\int_{x=0}^{2+\sqrt{4-(y-2)^2}}\int_{z=x^2+y^2}^{4y}dxdydz$$

Comment: @BabakS. I was almost there :) , Thanks you so much

Comment: @BabakS. i generally have problem with solving this kind of complex surfaces. Would you suggest some read or technique to work around them ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: If I wanted to solve this problem in my class, I would suggest students to do it by Cylindrical coordinates. It make the integrals easier. Adam's book is a very good help.

Comment: Nice work, dear friend!

Comment: in the cylindrical co-ordinates, i get the limit for $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and $r$ from $0$ to $4sin\theta$ . does that look good to you ?